# Скачивание файлов через ftp по маске

Tags: python

Как можно реализовать поиск по всем директориям и скачивание файлов на ftp сервере соответствующих маске?

Идеи:

```
import ftplib, re, os

FTP_HOST = ''
FTP_USER = ''
FTP_PASS = ''
ftp = ftplib.FTP(FTP_HOST, FTP_USER, FTP_PASS)
ftp.encoding = "utf-8"

pattern = r'LAST_REPORT_\d+\.txt'
pattern = re.compile(pattern)
root = ftp.cwd('/')

for folder, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for filename in files:
        if pattern.match(filename):
            with open(filename, "wb") as file:
                ftp.retrbinary("RETR %s" % filename, file.write)


ftp.quit()
```

Так же рассматривал вариант:

```
pattern = 'LAST_REPORT'
filesineed = [filename for filename in ftp.nlst() if pattern in filename]

for filename in filesineed:
    local_filename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        print('downloading {}...'.format(filename))
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, f.write)
```

Но он не рекурсивный и без использования регулярных выражений, не совсем то что нужно, однако работает :).

Comment: А что не так с вашим кодом, почему возник вопрос?

Comment: @CrazyElf не загружает файлы согласно маске

Comment: Попробуйте печатать `filename`, посмотрите что получается. Вообще файлы то перебираются? И посмотрите какой путь у файлов получается, может он не полный и его надо собирать из `folder` и `filename` или ещё как-то

Comment: @CrazyElf не выводится ничего, теперь я сомневаюсь что файлы вообще перебираются...

Comment: Ну вот я не уверен, что `os.walk` совместим с объектом, возвращаемым `ftp`. Может у библиотеки работы с ftp есть свой метод для получения списка файлов? Через какую библиотеку вы работаете с `ftp`, добавьте `import`-ы, и хорошо бы ещё команду инсталляции этой библиотеки написать.

Comment: Не могу найти ни одного публичного ftp сервера, чтобы попробовать код в деле. Раньше их полно было, а сейчас почти нет

Comment: @CrazyElf у яндекса кажется был  ftp://mirror.yandex.ru

Comment: Видимо, вам придётся перебирать файлы "вручную", используя команду `ftp.nlst`. А яндекс меня быстро забанил всего за несколько запросов.

Comment: @CrazyElf Жаль, я видел что там есть метод ftp.mlsd, более новый аналог предложенного вами, но думал что можно обойтись без него. По результату отпишу. Про яндекс аналогично жаль, теперь буду знать, спасибо вам.)